# Makefile fails with error no rule to make target

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm struggling to create a working make file.

**My structure**

- root/Makefile
- root/src/main.cpp
- root/include/

**My code**

```
# Define compiler
CC = g++

# Compiler flags
CFLAGS  = -g -Wall

# Build target executable
DIR = /src
INCLUDES = ../include
TARGET = main

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(TARGET).cpp
    cd $(DIR) &
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I $(INCLUDES) -o $(TARGET) $(TARGET).cpp

clean:
    cd $(DIR) &
    $(RM) $(TARGET)
```

**My Error**

make: *** No rule to make target `main.cpp', needed by`main'.  Stop.

**EDIT** 
Inside my main.cpp I have this line at the top which is meant to be found by my Makefile: `#include "pugixml.hpp"`

Comment: Considering your files, the target should be `$(TARGET): src/$(TARGET).cpp`

Comment: Hmm. Ok. Let me try that

Comment: @mpromonet That seems a lot closer but I get this: ```cd /src &
g++ -g -Wall -I ../include -o main main.cpp
/bin/sh: line 0: cd: /src: No such file or directory
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'main.cpp'
clang: error: no input files
make: *** [main] Error 1```

Comment: `DIR = /src` => this is an absolute path to which you are trying to `cd`

Comment: @peter I get the same error even when I do ```DIR = src```

Comment: Every line of a make recipe is run in its own shell. That `cd` command (which you run in the background for some reason) does not affect the next line's `$(CC)` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work for you.

All paths are given relative to the folder the Makefile is in. That means the source folder needs to be specified for the source dependencies.

```
# Define compiler
CC = g++

# Compiler flags
CFLAGS  = -g -Wall

# Build target executable
SRC = src
INCLUDES = include
TARGET = main

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(SRC)/$(TARGET).cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I $(INCLUDES) -o $@ $^ 

clean:
    $(RM) $(TARGET)
```

Use tabs (not spaces) for the commands.

`$@` resolves to the target (`main` in this case).

`$^` resolves to all of the dependencies (`src/main.cpp` in this case).

No need to `cd` into the source folder.